# How do I send the recorded data to the server after recording through MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now, I want the user to record and then send the recorded data to the server to get it back and play it on the timeline. At first, I created it as a blob and then tried to pass the url string to the server with createObjectUrl, but this is a one-time url, so when it is passed to the server and received, it is treated as an invalid address. So what's the other way? When I looked up, there were many cases where it was passed to the blob, but it was too slow to pass it to the blob. Isn't there a file object or something other than a blob pass?

Comment: post an arraybuffer? perhaps [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) is what you need

Comment: by the way, what you describe as "too slow", is it the actual transfer of data that's too slow? this can mean the bandwidth from client to server is slow - and no code is going to fix a physical speed issue